# Opening web camera in Google Colab

Tags: python, opencv, google-colaboratory

I am trying to open a web camera in Google Colab. I've executed the following command:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

but this is not working: the web camera is not opening.

Is it possible to open a connection to my web camera on Google Colab?

Comment: It's a Jupyter notebook, so the code runs on the "cloud" (i.e. on some remote server). It's unlikely that you will be able to plug a camera to the server it's running on, so trying to have `VideoCapture` read the first local (local to where the code runs) camera won't work.

Answer (score 45):

1. Go to Google Colaboratory
2. Create a new notebook
3. Click snippet panel
4. Click Camera Capture.
   Click insert
5. Run script:
   Shift + Enter

[image]

Comment: Snippet Panel can be found in Help > Search Code Snippets

Answer (score 27):

Since Colab is running in your browser, you'll want to use web APIs to access local hardware like a camera.

Here's an example showing how to capture an image from your local webcam in Colab:
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/advanced_outputs.ipynb#scrollTo=2viqYx97hPMi

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use your local runtime if you don't need to run your code on cloud.
Click here for more details on local runtime : https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html