# OpenCV(3.4.3) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor' error

Tags: opencv, google-colaboratory

I am new to OpenCV and Google Colab. I have been working on a project that requires me to take the real-time image frames from the webcam and process it. But the problem is from the below code the 'frame' always returns a 'None' type and my webcam does not seem to switch on. But using the example code from Colab to capture images works fine:

[How to use cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) in Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54389727/how-to-use-cap-cv2-videocapture0-in-google-colab)

Here is the code that fails:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = cap.read()
frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

```
---> 19     frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

error: OpenCV(3.4.3) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:181: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'
```

Comment: Seems like there is an issue with the capture itself, causing the grabbed image to be empty.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion to overcome that, because I've searched extensively and couldn't find any that solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

try replace the first line with

```
frame = cv2.imread('your_image.png',0)
```

If it works, then the high chance is your camera issue. 
There could be multiple reason. try

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
sudo apt-get install cheese
cheese
```

to see if you can get video feed in ubuntu. If can, then its opencv config issue. if cannot then its either driver or hardware issue.

If its driver issue. follow https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam to driver 
If hardware broke down, not much you can do software

Comment: I checked with the said replacement and it works fine and my camera is working fine too. Do you have anymore suggestions? Thanks in advance