# OpenCV not working in Google Colaboratory

Tags: python, opencv, google-colaboratory, face-recognition

I was practicing OpenCV on google colaboratory becasuse I don't know how to use OpenCV on GPU, when I run OpenCV on my hardware, It takes a lot of CPU, so I went to Google colaboratory.
The link to my notebook is [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1HWIRa7MXR3rysueUpzRSyRDLlZjiqPVH?usp=sharing).

If you don't want to watch it, then here is the code:

```
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow('img', img)

    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k==27:
        break
    
cap.release()
```

The same code worked fine on my PC, but not on Google Colaboratory. The error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-0d9472926d8c> in <module>()
      6 while True:
      7         _, img = cap.read()
----> 8         gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
      9         faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)
     10         for (x, y, w, h) in faces:

error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'
```

PS~I have the haarcascade file inside the same directory of my notebook in Google Colaboratory

How to deal with it? If not then is there any "**concrete**" solution to run OpenCV on my CUDA enabled GPU instead of CPU? Thanks in advance!

Comment: today I see second time the same problem - `_src.empty()` - it means that it had problem to get frame from camera and `img` is `None` and now it tries `cvtColor(None, ...) which gives  `_src.empty()` . You should check `if img is not None` because it doesn't raise error when it can't get frame. Sometimes camera need time to warm up and it can gives few empty frames (`None`).

Comment: But I think problem is that `VideoCapture(0)` reads frame from camera directly connected to computer which runs this code - and when you run code on server Google Colaboratory  then it means connected directly to server Google Colaboratory (not your local camera) but this server doesn't have camera - so it can't work on Google Colaboratory. You can't send image from your local camera to this server. Your web browser may have access to your camera but it need JavaScript to get frame and send to server - but server need code to get this frame - but Google Colaboratory doesn't have it.

Comment: I checked in Google if Google Colaboratory can access local webcam and it seems they created script for this - [Camera Capture](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/advanced_outputs.ipynb#scrollTo=2viqYx97hPMi)  - in first cell is function `take_photo()` which use JavaScript, and in second cell this function is used to display image from local camera.

Comment: @furas I think your comments should be answer. Also your other question about GPU and CUDA is another topic which is not related with current problem so you should ask it in another post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_src.empty()` means that it had problem to get frame from camera and `img` is `None` and when it tries `cvtColor(None, ...)` then it gives `_src.empty()`.

You should check `if img is not None:` because `cv2` doesn't raise error when it can't get frame from camera or read image from file. And sometimes camera needs time to "warm up" and it can gives few empty frames (`None`).

---

`VideoCapture(0)` reads frame from camera directly connected to computer which runs this code - and when you run code on server `Google Colaboratory` then it means camera connected directly to server `Google Colaboratory` (not your local camera) but this server doesn't have camera so `VideoCapture(0)` can't work on `Google Colaboratory`.

`cv2` can't get image from your local camera when it runs on server. Your web browser may have access to your camera but it needs JavaScript to get frame and send to server - but server needs code to get this frame

---

I checked in Google if `Google Colaboratory` can access local webcam and it seems they created script for this - [Camera Capture](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/advanced_outputs.ipynb#scrollTo=2viqYx97hPMi) - in first cell is function `take_photo()` which uses `JavaScript` to access your camera and display in browser, and in second cell this function is used to display image from local camera and to take screenshot.

You should use this function instead of `VideoCapture(0)` to work on server with your local camera.

---

**BTW:** Belove `take_photo()` there is also information about `cv2.im_show()` because it also works only with monitor directly connected to computer which runs this code (and this computer has to run GUI like `Windows` on Windows , `X11` on Linux) - and when you run it on server then it want to display on monitor directly connected to server - but server usually works without monitor (and without GUI)

`Google Colaboratory` has special replacement which displays in web browser

```
 from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
```

---

**BTW:** If you will have problem with loading haarcascades `.xml` then you may need folder to filename. `cv2` has special variable for this `cv2.data.haarcascades`

```
path = os.path.join(cv2.data.haarcascades, 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

cv2.CascadeClassifier( path )
```

You can also see what is in this folder

```
import os

filenames = os.listdir(cv2.data.haarcascades)
filenames = sorted(filenames)
print('\n'.join(filenames))
```

---

**EDIT:**

I created code which can get from local webcam frame by frame without using `button` and without saving in file. Problem is that it is slow - because it still have to send frame from local web browser to google colab server and later back to local web browser

Python code with JavaScript functions

```
#
# based on: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/advanced_outputs.ipynb#scrollTo=2viqYx97hPMi
#

from IPython.display import display, Javascript
from google.colab.output import eval_js
from base64 import b64decode, b64encode
import numpy as np

def init_camera():
  """Create objects and functions in HTML/JavaScript to access local web camera"""

  js = Javascript('''

    // global variables to use in both functions
    var div = null;
    var video = null;   // <video> to display stream from local webcam
    var stream = null;  // stream from local webcam
    var canvas = null;  // <canvas> for single frame from <video> and convert frame to JPG
    var img = null;     // <img> to display JPG after processing with `cv2`

    async function initCamera() {
      // place for video (and eventually buttons)
      div = document.createElement('div');
      document.body.appendChild(div);

      // <video> to display video
      video = document.createElement('video');
      video.style.display = 'block';
      div.appendChild(video);

      // get webcam stream and assing to <video>
      stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});
      video.srcObject = stream;

      // start playing stream from webcam in <video>
      await video.play();

      // Resize the output to fit the video element.
      google.colab.output.setIframeHeight(document.documentElement.scrollHeight, true);

      // <canvas> for frame from <video>
      canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
      canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
      //div.appendChild(input_canvas); // there is no need to display to get image (but you can display it for test)

      // <img> for image after processing with `cv2`
      img = document.createElement('img');
      img.width = video.videoWidth;
      img.height = video.videoHeight;
      div.appendChild(img);
    }

    async function takeImage(quality) {
      // draw frame from <video> on <canvas>
      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0);

      // stop webcam stream
      //stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();

      // get data from <canvas> as JPG image decoded base64 and with header "data:image/jpg;base64,"
      return canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', quality);
      //return canvas.toDataURL('image/png', quality);
    }

    async function showImage(image) {
      // it needs string "data:image/jpg;base64,JPG-DATA-ENCODED-BASE64"
      // it will replace previous image in `<img src="">`
      img.src = image;
      // TODO: create <img> if doesn't exists, 
      // TODO: use `id` to use different `<img>` for different image - like `name` in `cv2.imshow(name, image)`
    }

  ''')

  display(js)
  eval_js('initCamera()')

def take_frame(quality=0.8):
  """Get frame from web camera"""

  data = eval_js('takeImage({})'.format(quality))  # run JavaScript code to get image (JPG as string base64) from <canvas>

  header, data = data.split(',')  # split header ("data:image/jpg;base64,") and base64 data (JPG)
  data = b64decode(data)  # decode base64
  data = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.uint8)  # create numpy array with JPG data

  img = cv2.imdecode(data, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)  # uncompress JPG data to array of pixels

  return img

def show_frame(img, quality=0.8):
  """Put frame as <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,...."> """

  ret, data = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)  # compress array of pixels to JPG data

  data = b64encode(data)  # encode base64
  data = data.decode()  # convert bytes to string
  data = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + data  # join header ("data:image/jpg;base64,") and base64 data (JPG)

  eval_js('showImage("{}")'.format(data))  # run JavaScript code to put image (JPG as string base64) in <img>
                                           # argument in `showImage` needs `" "`
```

And code which uses it in loop

```
# 
# based on: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/advanced_outputs.ipynb#scrollTo=zo9YYDL4SYZr
#

#from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow  # I don't use it but own function `show_frame()`

import cv2
import os

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(os.path.join(cv2.data.haarcascades, 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'))

# init JavaScript code
init_camera()

while True:
    try:
        img = take_frame()

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        #cv2_imshow(gray)  # it creates new image for every frame (it doesn't replace previous image) so it is useless
        #show_frame(gray)  # it replace previous image

        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)

        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        
        #cv2_imshow(img)  # it creates new image for every frame (it doesn't replace previous image) so it is useless
        show_frame(img)  # it replace previous image
        
    except Exception as err:
        print('Exception:', err)
```

I don't use `from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow` because it always add new image on page instead of replacing existing image.

---

The same code as Notebook on Google Colab:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1j7HTapCLx7BQUBp3USiQPZkA0zBKgLM0?usp=sharing

Comment: I added information about variable `cv2.data.haarcascades`

Comment: I created code which get webcam code in loop without using button `Capture` - see code in answer - but it works very slow.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this code, it's pretty slow but better than nothing. I guess it's a technical problem and we will have to wait for Google Colab to sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

The possible problem in the code is, you need to give full-path as the directory when using Haar-like features.

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/User/path/to/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```

The `colab` issue with `opencv` has been known for quite some time, also the same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54389727/how-to-use-cap-cv2-videocapture0-in-google-colab)

As stated [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3935), you can use the `cv2_imshow` to display the image, but you want to process Camera frames.

```
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
img = cv2.imread('logo.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
cv2_imshow(img)
```

One possible answer:

Insert Camera Capture snippet, the method `take_photo`but you need to modify the method.

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

try:
    filename = take_photo()
    img = Image(filename)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    cv2_imshow("img", img)
      
except Exception as err:
    print(str(err))
```

The above code requires editing since there is no direct way to use `VideoCapture` you have to modify `take_photo`

Comment: BTW: there is special variable with folder name which have haarcascade files - `cv2.data.haarcascades`

Comment: Really? thanks for the information. Colab manages a video stream using javascript method named `take_photo()`, therefore to use haar features, `take_photo()` output should be used.

Comment: I know it - I already mentioned `take_photo()` in my answer. But I think it will need some changes because `take_photo()` wait for click on button `Capture` and it saves in file but original code needs to run with camera stream - so it can't wait for click and it don't need to save and read file. Now I try to change it.