# ROI selection cv2.selectROI not working in Google Colab

Tags: opencv, google-colaboratory

I’m learning opencv for object detection and trying to do all the coding using google colab. And so far it has been working well: I can mount the gdrive and upload file and read the video file just fine.

The selecting ROI by passing video frame into cv2.selectROI() crashed the Colab. The runtime log complained about a plugin xcb not initialising. Further reading reveals the plug in require to be run on local machine, so I wonder if there is a way to run cv2.selectROI or equivalent on colab?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63590320/opencv-not-working-in-google-colaboratory

Comment: @toyotaSupra nice car. Thank you for the link, yes I read it. and it nicely explained the reason of my problem. I wonder if there is a similar workaround for video and ROI selection like for cv2.imshow ? like the mentioned.    from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow.

Comment: Thank. I don't third party from google.colab.patches.

Comment: If you post code. Someone maybe trying to help you.