# Google Colab : "Live video streaming using webcam"

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, video-streaming, google-colaboratory, conv-neural-network

I am trying to learn how to detect a mask on a live video using Google Colab. Although I can use the code of the camera to capture images. But I can not stream a live video. How can that be done? Here is the sample code of my project. It is done on a local computer using the VideoCapture(0). VideoCapture returns value and image type. But when I used the code of take_photo() in colab it doesn't return as the same as VideoCapture Functions in my second code's 2nd line. That's why I can not get the result.

```
 face_clsfr = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/dataset/face mask detection/face detection.xml') #path of facedetection xml file
    source = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #video capture on camera 0 
    labels_dict = {0: 'Mask !!!' , 1: ' No Mask !!!'}
    color_dict = {0:(0,255,0) , 1:(255,0,0)} # rgb color
```

and

```
while(True):

    ret,img=source.read()
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces=face_clsfr.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)  

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    
        face_img=gray[y:y+w,x:x+w]
        resized=cv2.resize(face_img,(100,100))
        normalized=resized/255.0
        reshaped=np.reshape(normalized,(1,100,100,1))
        result=model.predict(reshaped)

        label=np.argmax(result,axis=1)[0]
      
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),color_dict[label],2)
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y-40),(x+w,y),color_dict[label],-1)
        cv2.putText(img, labels_dict[label], (x, y-10),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.8,(255,255,255),2)
        
        
    cv2.imshow('LIVE',img)
    key=cv2.waitKey(1)
    
    if(key==27):
        break
        
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
source.release()
```

How can I solve this problem? How can I run this model in colab using live video streaming and what do I need to replace this "ret,img=source.read()" (in my second code's 2nd line)to run the model? This is my project [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LkteD_H0X-7nIRw6JVc2l9zUUZsJKZvR#scrollTo=7e4WBoyEPp_I) .
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) in Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54389727/how-to-use-cap-cv2-videocapture0-in-google-colab)

Comment: no.there is a little bit of difference between this question with this question. what things do I need to replace with this  "ret,img=source.read() ' (in 2nd code's 2nd line)? by using the mentioned question's answer I didn't run the model. This is my project link : [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LkteD_H0X-7nIRw6JVc2l9zUUZsJKZvR#scrollTo=7e4WBoyEPp_I)