# using openCV to open the webcam and take picture with it every five seconds

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I tried to use the webcam and take pictures every 5 seconds via openCV but the cam itself didn't work and kept causing the error...
I also tried changing the integer in the cv2.VideoCapture() to -1 and 1 but still that didn't work.

This is the form of the error: "[ WARN:0] global /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (802)
open VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: can't open camera by index 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "webcam_detect.py", line 176, in 
raise IOError("Cannot open webcam")
OSError: Cannot open webcam"

```
import colorsys
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0'
import cv2
import time


import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.layers import Input

from yolo3.model import yolo_eval, yolo_body, tiny_yolo_body
from yolo3.utils import image_preporcess

class YOLO(object):
    _defaults = {
        #"model_path": 'logs/trained_weights_final.h5',
        "model_path": 'model_data/yolo_weights.h5',
        "anchors_path": 'model_data/yolo_anchors.txt',
        "classes_path": 'model_data/coco_classes.txt',
        "score" : 0.3,
        "iou" : 0.45,
        "model_image_size" : (416, 416),
        "text_size" : 1,
    }

@classmethod
def get_defaults(cls, n):
    if n in cls._defaults:
        return cls._defaults[n]
    else:
        return "Unrecognized attribute name '" + n + "'"

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.__dict__.update(self._defaults) # set up default values
    self.__dict__.update(kwargs) # and update with user overrides
    self.class_names = self._get_class()
    self.anchors = self._get_anchors()
    self.sess = K.get_session()
    self.boxes, self.scores, self.classes = self.generate()

def _get_class(self):
    classes_path = os.path.expanduser(self.classes_path)
    with open(classes_path) as f:
        class_names = f.readlines()
    class_names = [c.strip() for c in class_names]
    return class_names

def _get_anchors(self):
    anchors_path = os.path.expanduser(self.anchors_path)
    with open(anchors_path) as f:
        anchors = f.readline()
    anchors = [float(x) for x in anchors.split(',')]
    return np.array(anchors).reshape(-1, 2)

def generate(self):
    model_path = os.path.expanduser(self.model_path)
    assert model_path.endswith('.h5'), 'Keras model or weights must be a .h5 file.'

    # Load model, or construct model and load weights.
    num_anchors = len(self.anchors)
    num_classes = len(self.class_names)
    is_tiny_version = num_anchors==6 # default setting
    try:
        self.yolo_model = load_model(model_path, compile=False)
    except:
        self.yolo_model = tiny_yolo_body(Input(shape=(None,None,3)), num_anchors//2, num_classes) \
            if is_tiny_version else yolo_body(Input(shape=(None,None,3)), num_anchors//3, num_classes)
        self.yolo_model.load_weights(self.model_path) # make sure model, anchors and classes match
    else:
        assert self.yolo_model.layers[-1].output_shape[-1] == \
            num_anchors/len(self.yolo_model.output) * (num_classes + 5), \
            'Mismatch between model and given anchor and class sizes'

    print('{} model, anchors, and classes loaded.'.format(model_path))

    # Generate colors for drawing bounding boxes.
    hsv_tuples = [(x / len(self.class_names), 1., 1.)
                  for x in range(len(self.class_names))]
    self.colors = list(map(lambda x: colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(*x), hsv_tuples))
    self.colors = list(
        map(lambda x: (int(x[0] * 255), int(x[1] * 255), int(x[2] * 255)),
            self.colors))

    np.random.shuffle(self.colors)  # Shuffle colors to decorrelate adjacent classes.

    # Generate output tensor targets for filtered bounding boxes.
    self.input_image_shape = K.placeholder(shape=(2, ))
    boxes, scores, classes = yolo_eval(self.yolo_model.output, self.anchors,
            len(self.class_names), self.input_image_shape,
            score_threshold=self.score, iou_threshold=self.iou)
    return boxes, scores, classes

def detect_image(self, image):
    if self.model_image_size != (None, None):
        assert self.model_image_size[0]%32 == 0, 'Multiples of 32 required'
        assert self.model_image_size[1]%32 == 0, 'Multiples of 32 required'
        boxed_image = image_preporcess(np.copy(image), tuple(reversed(self.model_image_size)))
        image_data = boxed_image

    out_boxes, out_scores, out_classes = self.sess.run(
        [self.boxes, self.scores, self.classes],
        feed_dict={
            self.yolo_model.input: image_data,
            self.input_image_shape: [image.shape[0], image.shape[1]],#[image.size[1], image.size[0]],
            K.learning_phase(): 0
        })

    #print('Found {} boxes for {}'.format(len(out_boxes), 'img'))

    thickness = (image.shape[0] + image.shape[1]) // 600
    fontScale=1
    ObjectsList = []
    
    for i, c in reversed(list(enumerate(out_classes))):
        predicted_class = self.class_names[c]
        box = out_boxes[i]
        score = out_scores[i]

        label = '{} {:.2f}'.format(predicted_class, score)
        #label = '{}'.format(predicted_class)
        scores = '{:.2f}'.format(score)

        top, left, bottom, right = box
        top = max(0, np.floor(top + 0.5).astype('int32'))
        left = max(0, np.floor(left + 0.5).astype('int32'))
        bottom = min(image.shape[0], np.floor(bottom + 0.5).astype('int32'))
        right = min(image.shape[1], np.floor(right + 0.5).astype('int32'))

        mid_h = (bottom-top)/2+top
        mid_v = (right-left)/2+left

        # put object rectangle
        cv2.rectangle(image, (left, top), (right, bottom), self.colors[c], thickness)

        # get text size
        (test_width, text_height), baseline = cv2.getTextSize(label, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, thickness/self.text_size, 1)

        # put text rectangle
        cv2.rectangle(image, (left, top), (left + test_width, top - text_height - baseline), self.colors[c], thickness=cv2.FILLED)

        # put text above rectangle
        cv2.putText(image, label, (left, top-2), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, thickness/self.text_size, (0, 0, 0), 1)

        # add everything to list
        ObjectsList.append([top, left, bottom, right, mid_v, mid_h, label, scores])

    return image, ObjectsList

def close_session(self):
    self.sess.close()

def detect_img(self, image):
    #image = cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    original_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    original_image_color = cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    
    r_image, ObjectsList = self.detect_image(original_image_color)
    return r_image, ObjectsList


if __name__=="__main__":
    yolo = YOLO()

    # set start time to current time
    #start_time = time.time()
    # displays the frame rate every 2 second
    #display_time = 2
    # Set primarry FPS to 0
    #fps = 0

    # we create the video capture object cap
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    if not cap.isOpened():
      raise IOError("Cannot open webcam")
    cap.set(3, 640)
    cap.set(4,480)
    img_counter=0
    frame_set=[]
    start_time=time.time()
    #if not cap.isOpened():
        #raise IOError("We cannot open webcam")

    #while True:
        #ret, frame = cap.read()
        # resize our captured frame if we need
        #frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=1.0, fy=1.0, 
         interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

        # detect object on our frame
        #r_image, ObjectsList = yolo.detect_img(frame)

        # show us frame with detection
        #cv2.imshow("Web cam input", r_image)
        #if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            #cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            #break

        # calculate FPS
        #fps += 1
        #TIME = time.time() - start_time
        #if TIME > display_time:
            #print("FPS:", fps / TIME)
            #fps = 0 
            #start_time = time.time()
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=1.0, fy=1.0, 
        interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        r_image, ObjectsList=yolo.detect_img(frame)
        cv2.imshow('Web cam input', r_image)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        if time.time() - start_time >= 5: #<---- Check if 5 sec passed
            img_name = "opencv_frame_{}.png".format(img_counter)
            cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
            print("{} written!".format(img_counter))
            start_time = time.time()
        img_counter += 1
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    yolo.close_session()
```

Comment: Are you on Linux? If so, do you see `/dev/video0` or anything similar from the command `ls /dev/video*` ?

Comment: No im not using linux. Running this code on windows10 in colab itself

Comment: So assuming you can open the webcam with the Windows 10 camera application, the problem is probably with colab. I don't know anything about colab, but if you search `colab camera access`, you'll get probably helpful results such as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54389727/how-to-use-cap-cv2-videocapture0-in-google-colab