# cv2 videocapture webcam not opening on google collab

Tags: python

my cv2 code is working fine. I've imported all the necessary libraries but when i run the code, webcam doen't open. I'm following this code tutorial:
https://github.com/nicknochnack/FaceRecognition

```
# Establish a connected to do webcam
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(4)
    while cap.isOpened():
      ret , frame = cap.read()
      
      # Cut down frame to 250x250px
      frame = frame[120:120+250, 200:200+250, :]
      
      # Collect anchors
      if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0XFF == ord('a'):
        # Create the unique file path
        imgname = os.path.join(ANC_PATH, '{}.jpg'.format(uuid.uuid1()))
        # Write out anchor image
        cv2.imwrite(imgname , frame)
     
      # Collect positives
      if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0XFF == ord('p'):
        # Create the unique file path
        imgname = os.path.join(POS_PATH, '{}.jpg'.format(uuid.uuid1()))
        # Write out anchor image
        cv2.imwrite(imgname , frame)
     
      # Show image back to  screen
      cv2.imshow('Image Collection', frame)
      
      # Braking gracefully 
      if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0XFF == ord('q'):
        break
    
     # Release the webcam      
    cap.release()
    # Close the image show frame 
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening web camera in Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54389727/opening-web-camera-in-google-colab)

Comment: the webcam does open with the method you shared, but I'm trying to open a new tab titled 'IMage Collection'. I can't seem to do that.

Comment: Import following: `from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow` and use `cv2_imshow()` instead of `cv2.imshow()`.