# Camera is not opening to capture videos by Open-CV

Tags: python, opencv, google-colaboratory, webcam

The following code is run on Google Colab and it shows "Your session is crushed. Automatically restarting". I am beginner and I need to use the camera to capture face expressions.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
cap = cv.VideoCapture(-1)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open camera")
    exit()
while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # if frame is read correctly ret is True
    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break
    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv.imshow('frame', gray)
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Zero mean one camera one mean two camera and so on. cv.VideoCapture(0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening web camera in Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54389727/opening-web-camera-in-google-colab)

Answer (score 0):

There is no local video device in the Colab environment; it's running somewhere in the cloud. What is needed is some JavaScript locally in the browser to get access to a camera near the user. Colab provides code snippet examples and one is for video capture which I've included below.

Run this cell first.

```
from IPython.display import display, Javascript
from google.colab.output import eval_js
from base64 import b64decode

def take_photo(filename='photo.jpg', quality=0.8):
js = Javascript('''
  async function takePhoto(quality) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    const capture = document.createElement('button');
    capture.textContent = 'Capture';
    div.appendChild(capture);

    const video = document.createElement('video');
    video.style.display = 'block';
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});

    document.body.appendChild(div);
    div.appendChild(video);
    video.srcObject = stream;
    await video.play();

    // Resize the output to fit the video element.
    google.colab.output.setIframeHeight(document.documentElement.scrollHeight, true);

    // Wait for Capture to be clicked.
    await new Promise((resolve) => capture.onclick = resolve);

    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
    canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0);
    stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
    div.remove();
    return canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', quality);
  }
  ''')
display(js)
data = eval_js('takePhoto({})'.format(quality))
binary = b64decode(data.split(',')[1])
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
  f.write(binary)
return filename
```

You'll have to allow video access when running this cell.

```
from IPython.display import Image
try:
  filename = take_photo()
  print('Saved to {}'.format(filename))

  # Show the image which was just taken.
  display(Image(filename))
except Exception as err:
  # Errors will be thrown if the user does not have a webcam or if they do not
  # grant the page permission to access it.
  print(str(err))
```

Comment: Can't thank you enough. It worked.