# How can I evaluate Yolov8 model on Google Colab with webcam

Tags: python, computer-vision, google-colaboratory, yolo, yolov5

I have trained both `yolov7` and `yolov8` models on my customer dataset, and I want to evaluate these models on webcam.

While I understand the google colab don't work with webcam by default, I have used the patch on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54389727/opening-web-camera-in-google-colab) page to make `yolov7` work, but it doesn't work for `yolov8`. Now I try to run the inference directly on `yolov8` with webcam using the syntax below:

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/yolov8/Mask-Wearing-19/runs/detect/train2/weights/best.pt')
result = model.predict(source = '0', show = True)
print(result)
```

But I got the error beneath it:

```
Ultralytics YOLOv8.0.47  Python-3.8.10 torch-1.13.1+cu116 CUDA:0 (Tesla T4, 15102MiB)
Model summary (fused): 168 layers, 3006038 parameters, 0 gradients, 8.1 GFLOPs

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-fb6ca5e1217d> in <module>
----> 1 result = model.predict(source = '0', show = True)
      2 print(result)

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ultralytics/yolo/data/dataloaders/stream_loaders.py in __init__(self, sources, imgsz, stride, auto, transforms, vid_stride)
     51             s = eval(s) if s.isnumeric() else s  # i.e. s = '0' local webcam
     52             if s == 0 and (is_colab() or is_kaggle()):
---> 53                 raise NotImplementedError("'source=0' webcam not supported in Colab and Kaggle notebooks. "
     54                                           "Try running 'source=0' in a local environment.")
     55             cap = cv2.VideoCapture(s)

NotImplementedError: 'source=0' webcam not supported in Colab and Kaggle notebooks. Try running 'source=0' in a local environment.
```

Could you help me to figure out why it has happened?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take a look here [Colab with Yolo live](https://colab.research.google.com/github/isnamdnazim/YOLO-V4-Object-Detection/blob/main/Real_time_YOLOv4_Object_Detection_on_Webcam_in_Google_Colab_%7C_Images_and_Video.ipynb), But for YoloV8 I think the builtin method dosen't support working with colab.But if you run this code on your local machine it will run.