# Unable to use webcam for live gesture recognition on Colab

Tags: opencv, google-colaboratory

> Important: This question is not a duplicate of
> [Opening web camera in Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54389727/opening-web-camera-in-google-colab)
> and I have explained the reason within the question.

I am trying to create a gesture recognizer using MediaPipe on Google Colab. The idea behind this program is that the user would do hand gestures in front of the camera and the code will recognize it instantly. However, since it is running on Colab, the code is unable to recognize the local webcam. Locally, I am trying to capture the webcam feed using `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`.

Now let me explain why this question is not a duplicate. All the previous solutions were for reading images and not live feed using the webcam. Which is why they don't work in my case. Also, the snippet given in Colab is once again for images and uploaded videos but not for live feed.

Comment: same issue. the code runs on a google server, not in your browser. capturing single images or "a live feed" is functionally the same task. the only solutions I've seen contain browser-side javascript that reads from the webcam and then pushes that data to the notebook running on the colab server.