# Camera access for real time video

Tags: python, camera, google-colaboratory

Im working on google colab and when i want to use my laptop camera for a real time video its not working
I gave it the permision to reach and still failed to captuer??

I want to apply real time video using my laptop camera but it didnt happend

Comment: You should [edit] to provide more details about how you are trying to use your laptop camera on Google Colab, and what "*is not working*" means. But just FYI, Google Colaboratory is running the code in the "cloud", on Google's servers. It has no access to your machine's camera.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54389727/2745495